# Rails join table A to table C where A has many B and B has many C

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

So in rails, I have

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :boxes

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :items
belongs_to :organization

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :box
```

Without adding the association on Organization, how can I query for all items that belong to an organization? I don't want to add orgaization_id to Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`has_many :through` Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

In your case, you can add the following to your `Organization` model

```
has_many :items, through: :boxes
```

Then you'll be able to write something like this: `Organization.find_by(id: ..., name: ....).items`

Comment: That seems totally reasonable! I was thinking about joins but probably not necessary. Thx